# Android View get original "Wrap Content" Size of my view

Tags: android, view, kotlin

I have a question about Android Views that appears to have been asked several times. But still I never get exactly the answer I need.
I have to create a View that changes it's size (height) according to a given percentage. That means, I want something like

```
setHeight(percentage){
     view.setHeight(Originl * percentage)
}
```

In order to do so, I need the original height of the view without any changes or the outer layout (so no Match_Parent).
There are many ways and possible moments to calculate the views height but they all seem to have the current height as a result - not the "desired" one.

For instance I tried to use onMeasure() since this is the moment when the view is measured but it is also called when changing the views heigh. It also is done on the view "creation" several time. So I can't even take the first value that comes because it sometimes is called twice with the first measurement giving wrong data (e.g. a height of 0 until the second onMeasure gives the real one).

I now did something that is also not really great but seems to work. I added a Listener like that

```
getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener( this)
```

and in the callback method I remove the listener

```
override fun onGlobalLayout() {
        Log.d("OnGlobalLayout", "Height: $height")
        originalHeight = height
        getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener( this)
}
```

This seems to work more or less but is that really the way to do? I was hoping for some method that gets the expected view size no matter what the current one is.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can write an extension once for views like that

```
inline fun View.afterMeasured(crossinline f: View.() -> Unit) {
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            if (measuredHeight > 0 && measuredWidth > 0) {
                viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                f()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Than just write

```
    mView.afterMeasured {
      // inside this block the view is completely drawn,
      // here you have an access for its height and width
    }
```

Comment: Well, thats at least a cleaner solution. But is this really the best way to do that?